# Explicit model of BSU(2) in terms of singular complex 

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

What is the explicit model of BSU(2) in terms of singular complex, up to 5 dimensions,
so that one can compute $\pi_5(BSU(2))=\mathbb{Z}_2$ explicitly?

This question is related to another question of $\pi$-cohomology and its computation.
(see [$\pi$-cohomology class -- a variant of cohomology class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123501/pi-cohomology-class-a-variant-of-cohomology-class) )

Comment: I changed 'homotopy' to 'homotopy-theory'; I am not sure this is the most fitting, but in any case there are already *nine* tags containing homotopy. To create the *unspecific* 'homotopy' as tenth thus seems not optimal to me.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise on what it means for you, to compute homotopy groups of spaces explicitly, if you do not allow yourself the tool (as Andre did) of the long exact sequence of a fibration? 

Comment: @Ryan: I would like to know an explicit singular complex (or an explicit simplicial set) that homotopically model $BSU(2)$, so that I can computer other topological properties of $BSU(2)$ in a finite calculation. The model does not have to be complete, since I am only interested in the topological properties at dimensions up to 5 or 6.
I mention $\pi_5(BSU(2))$ because I like to model to be complete enough to computer $\pi_5(BSU(2))$.


Comment: If I had a  singular complex (or an explicit simplicial set) that homotopically model $BSU(2)$, then I list all the homotopically equivalent 5-spheres in $BSU(2)$, which will be a finite list.

Comment: @Xiao-Gang Wen. "then I list all the homotopically equivalent 5-spheres": I hope that I'm not being offensive, but to be quite honest your proposal sounds like complete crazyness. Can you name *any* simplicial set in which you can make a complete list of the 5-spheres that live in it? Let's start with an easier example: the well known $\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb Z$. It's easy to model $S^2$ by a simplicial complex, for example the boundary of a tetrahedron. Can you use that description to compute $\pi_3(S^2)$?

Comment: @Andre: I see your point. The list may be infinite even
if we just list all the homotopically equivalent 5-spheres
of one particular type.  I would like to have a singular complex model, hoping to compute the $\pi$-cohomology (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123501/pi-cohomology-class-a-variant-of-cohomology-class )


Comment: @Xiao-Gang: I found it hard to follow your proposal for the definition of $\pi$-cohomology. But algebraic topologists do have an assortment of theories that in some sense refine ordinary cohomology - notably, (co)bordism theories - which are accessible from cellular descriptions of the spaces, though harder to compute than ordinary cohomology. You might think about whether those are relevant to the problems you are working on.

Comment: @Tim: Thank you very much for the suggestions. Indeed, motivated by a physics problem, I need this slightly refined definition of cohomology - $\pi$-cohomology. It is possible that at the end
the more general definition might lead to the same usual cohomology.
In any case, I need to find ways to compute $\pi$-cohomology
which involve both cohomology and homotopy. I am hoping knowing the the singlar complex model of BSU(2) may help us to do the computation. But I have no formal math background. I need something very elementary. Singlar complex model may turn cohomology theory into linear alg.
 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that a singular complex is not the best option if you are interesting in computing topological properties of $BSU(2) \approx \mathbb HP^\infty$ by a "finite calculation". A singular $n$-simplex is just a continuous map from the standard $n$-simplex to the manifold, there are thus ucountable infinite number of them for any $n$. A simplicial, $\Delta$ or CW complex is a much simpler and more efficient for calculations, CW complex probably being the best one.

I have tried to construct the CW complex concretely (by extending example 0.4, 0.5 and 0.6 of [Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) to the quaternionic case), and if I am right then you have the following CW decomposition

$\mathbb HP^n = e^0 \cup e^4 \cup \cdots \cup e^{4n}$.

For example for $\mathbb HP^1$, you just have one $1$-cell and one $4$-cell. For the classifying space, $\mathbb HP^\infty$, you have a countable number of cells, only one for each $4n$-cell.

Let me briefly go through how it's done (thinking about the $\mathbb RP^n$ case first, might make this much easier to understand).

One way do define $\mathbb HP^n$ is to identify any two points on the unit quaternionic sphere $p,q\in S(\mathbb H^{n+1})\approx S^{4n+3}$ by $p\sim q$ iff $p=\lambda q$, where $\lambda\in S^3 \approx SU(2)$ is a unit quaternion.

This is however equivalent to taking a disk ("upper hemisphere")
$D^{4n}_+ = \left\{\left(w,\sqrt{1-|w|^2}\right)\in\mathbb H^n\times\mathbb H | |w|\leq 1\right\}\subset S^{4n+3}$ and identifying the points on the boundary by $a\sim b$ iff $a=\lambda b$. The boundary is just $\partial D^{4n}_+=S^{4n-1} = S^{4(n-1)+3}$ with elements $(w,0)$, where $w\in\mathbb H^n$ and $|w|^2=1$. Therefore this identification on the boundary just leads to $\mathbb HP^{n-1}$, "on the boundary".

In other words, to construct $\mathbb HP^n$, take the disjoint union of a $4n$-disk and $\mathbb HP^{n-1}$, then attach the disk boundary to $\mathbb HP^{n-1}$ by the natural projection

$\pi:\partial D^{4n}_+ = S^{4(n-1)+3}\rightarrow \mathbb HP^{n-1},$ $a\mapsto [a]$.

Thus we can construct a CW complex;

1. Start with a $0$-skeleton $X^0$ containing only one $0$-cell (one point). Add a $4$-disk and attach its boundary ($S^3$) to the $0$-cell (point) to get the $4$-skeleton $X^4 = S^4 = \mathbb HP^1$ with only one $4$-cell.
2. Add a $8$-disk to $X^4$ and glue its boundary ($S^7$) to $X^4=\mathbb HP^1$ by the projection map $\pi$, and obtain $X^8=\mathbb HP^2$.
3. Continue until the $n$-skeleton $X^n = \mathbb HP^n$.

So we have the inclusions $\mathbb HP^0 \subset\mathbb HP^1 \subset\mathbb HP^2 \subset \dots \subset \mathbb HP^n$,

given iteratively

$\mathbb HP^n = \frac{\mathbb HP^{n-1}\sqcup D^{4n}_+}{a \sim \pi(a)} = e^0\cup e^4\cup\cdots\cup e^{4n}$.

This construction contain relatively few cells and might be effectively used to calculate the $\pi$-cohomology. If you prefer a triangulation, the [appendix of Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATsimplicial.pdf) is probably good to read in order to see how one might decompose this cell-decomposition into a triangulation.

(I feel I made this seem more formal and technical than it is.)

Edit:

If you are interested in a simplicial/CW complex of $BSU(2)=\mathbb HP^\infty$ which is just accurate enough to get $\pi_5(BSU(2)) = \mathbb Z_2$ right, then $\mathbb HP^1$ might be a good enough approximation to $BSU(2)$. According to the above construction we have that $\mathbb HP^1 = S^4$, and it is well-known that $\pi_5(S^4)=\mathbb Z_2$ (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table)). If $\mathbb HP^1 = S^4$ is enough to calculate the $\pi$-cohomology, then it is very simple to get a simplicial complex for this without the need of a CW complex.

Edit 2:

By the way, $\mathbb HP^1=S^4$ seems to get everything up to (and including) $\pi_6(BSU(2))$ right but it fails after that. Actually $\pi_{i\geq 7}(S^4)$ has all the right factors from $\pi_{i\geq 7}(BSU(2))$, and some additional factors. I think if you use $\mathbb HP^2$ as an approximation instead, then some of these extra factors vanish and a few more homotopy groups turn out correctly. Thus $\mathbb HP^1 = S^4$ seems to be an okay approximation if you are only interested in homotopy up to $\pi_6(BSU(2))$.

Answer (score 5):

The infinite quaternionic sphere $S(\mathbb{H}^\infty)=\bigcup_n{S(\mathbb{H}^n)}$ is contractible and carries a free action of the unit quaternions $SU(2)=Sp(1)$. The quotient $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$ is a model for $BSU(2)$, and $\mathbb{H}P^n$ is then an approximation suitable for computing homotopy groups or the cohomology ring in low degrees.

Comment: @Tim: This is something I want, which is in terms of CW complex (?). But what is the singular complex (or the simplicial set) that model $\mathbb{H}P^n$. I like to know how many edges, how many faces, and how are they connected. May be a singular complex (or the simplicial set) that model $\mathbb{H}P^2$ is enough for me.

Comment: This description should indeed yield a CW complex, and from that one could I suppose work out a triangulation. But, like André Henriques, I find it hard to believe that triangulation is an effective way to extract information (compare the standard treatments of $BU(1)$ and $B(\mathbb{Z}/2)$).

Answer (score 4):

If you care about homotopy groups of classifying spaces, then the relevant general result is $\pi_n(BG)=\pi_{n-1}(G)$.

In your specific case, you are looking at $\pi_4(SU(2))=\pi_4(S^3)=\mathbb Z/2$.

For any $n\ge 3$, one has $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)=\mathbb Z/2$.
This is the first stable homotopy group of spheres $\pi_1^{st}(S^0)$, and its generator is one of the three ``Hopf invariant one'' elements.

Comment: @Andre Thank you for the answer. Actually, I do not care about $\pi_n(BSU(2))$. I like to know an explicit singular complex (or
an explicit simplicial set) that model the $BSU(2)$ in a homotopically equivalent way. This will allow me to compute homotopical and/or homological properties of $BSU(2)$ in a finite calculation.

Comment: "This will allow me to compute homotopical and/or homological properties": there are other way of computing everything you might want to know about BSU(2) that are much better than having an explicit simplicial set.